# Designer Layout doesn't show correctly in Custom Dialog

Tags: android, xml, dialog

I designed a setting dialog layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dip"
    android:weightSum="1" android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:text="Sound Options:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="5dip">

            <TextView android:text="Background Sounds:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/butBackgroundSound"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ToggleButton>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="5dip">

            <TextView android:text="Effect Sounds:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/butEffectSound"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ToggleButton>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the preview of that layout (and it is correct):

[image]

However, when inside Dialog, it is like this:

[image]

I don't know why there's always a blank space at the top, it happens in all my project, then, the dialog is completely ruined in this project. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for remove black space try this line in your code of dialog..

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and set property

```
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

for top two parent layout.. in your case set this property for top two linearlayout.

Comment: The top blank space has been removed, but the dialog's size is still not correct. The ToggleButton is almost completely disappeared. And later I will need other options, so I don't think set Sound Options's Layout to fill_parent is a good idea.

Comment: just remove android:gravity="center" and  android:weightSum="1" check what will happen

Comment: Still not works. I deleted the LinearLayout layout_weight too!

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Can you please post your working XML content (by editing your answer), maybe I could find out myself?

Comment: see my another answer it is displaying all view but not in fullscreen

Answer (score 2):

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dip">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:text="Sound Options:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></TextView>


        <TextView android:text="Background Sounds:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"></TextView>
        <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/butBackgroundSound"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"></ToggleButton>


        <TextView android:text="Effect Sounds:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/butBackgroundSound"></TextView>
        <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/butEffectSound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3" android:layout_below="@+id/butBackgroundSound"></ToggleButton>



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice, it works :) You didn't tell me to use RelativeLayout, lol :D

Comment: OK, maybe I still need it (RelativeLayout) anyway, the buttons should all be at the right for better visual.